# Sound Effect Used in Dubbing Foreign Movies/ Translation

Tags: sound-effects, software, sound-effects-recording, film-sound-design, sound-libraries

In many of the dubbed tv episodes of discovery channel and Nat Geo, the voice of the language of the speaker is converted but the sound seems to be the same.

I have seen this in even dubbed movies. The voice in both languages seems eerily similar.

What sound effect is used? Recently, Mark Zuckerbeg made an ai assistant in Morgan Freeman's voice. See it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGLPxEv_EWo).

Is there any sound procesing library in Python (proramming language) to create that kind of effect (make morgan freeman speak my text).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No software magic required...

The trick is... you book a voiceover artist/actor who sounds like the person you're dubbing.
That simple.

Answer (score 1):

As with the other answer, I'm sure its just the VO talent trying to match the original performance, pitch, and timbre.  Of course, they probably choose someone with a very similar voice to start with, but good VO talent can have a wide range, and be able to recognize what they need to sound like.

For timing purposes they listen to the original language before each take.